# TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping inside StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a StackPanel, but the following line :

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Notes}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
```

is not Wrapping the Text.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=Id, StringFormat='#\{0\}'}" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Time, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" />
        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="6"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Source="{Binding Path=Image, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Notes}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <Image
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Source="{Binding Path=Picture, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PictureConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The `StackPanel` Orientation is set to 'Vertical' but the `TextBlock` is not inheriting it.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your problem is using the `StackPanel` that allows its children to fill in all the available space - the `StackPanel` stretches accordingly to the size of its content. Try removing the `StackPanel` and keep just the `Grid` - this way you will limit the size of its children to the available space used by the Grid.

If that isn't enough in the layout you've built, try setting a MaxWidth on the `TextBox` that needs wrapping.

Now the source of your problem was also the fact that your `TextBox` was inserted in the first  Column of the `Grid` that had an infinite size (Width="Auto"). Thus, setting the Grid.Column="7" to the `TextBox` did the trick you wanted (wrapping text). Here's the revised code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=Id, StringFormat='#\{0\}'}" />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Time, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" />
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="6"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Source="{Binding Path=Image, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Text="{Binding Notes}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <Image
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="4"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Source="{Binding Path=Picture, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PictureConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```