# how to wrap text in gridview - windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

i am using [grid view control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780650.aspx) for to show data,

problem is, my few text is very long and it is not warping correctlly

[image]

xaml is like this :

```
<GridView x:Name="itemGridView" Grid.Row="2" Margin="30,20,0,0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView" AutomationProperties.Name="Items"  TabIndex="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding EquipBookingCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}" SelectionMode="None" IsSwipeEnabled="false" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

and ItemTemplate is like this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Start Time : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookedFromDteTme }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Finish Time: " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookedToDteTme }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Task Address : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskAddress}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Task Description : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Client Company : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientCompany}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Status Name : " Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status.Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0" Foreground="Red"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

please help me with this, thanks

Comment: Do you want the description to go to next line as being multiline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a related issue to [TextBlock TextWrapping not wrapping inside StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430705/textblock-textwrapping-not-wrapping-inside-stackpanel)

In short, you'll want to stop using StackPanel control and use the much better Grid control instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width property of  textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BookedFromDteTme }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0" Width = "200"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of StackPanel you can use WrapPanel

```
        </WrapPanel>
```