# How to create a multiline label in StackLayout/Grid for UWP?

Tags: xamarin, label, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I haven't found out how to have a multiline label for UWP. In my real project I have the label in a `Grid` on a `ViewCell` in a `ListView`. For the below example I've put it into a `StackLayout`:

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label x:Name="titleLabel" Text="some long text" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
    <Label x:Name="valueLabel" Text="perhaps a much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much longer text" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
</StackLayout>
```

The code is working on iOS and Android, but not on UWP. Here the text gets cut off. If only one label and no `StackLayout` is used it appears correctly on UWP with the multiline text.

I also tried to use a custom renderer with a multiline `TextBlock` as label, but the result was the same - the text is cut off.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

Now I made a UWP project

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="oh this is a label" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock Text="and this should be a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long text" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
```

and here the text is also cut off. It seems it isn't possible in UWP. Are there any other solutions/workarounds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set a `WidthRequest` for each label, the multiline label is correctly displayed (by growing in height).

An alternative solution is e.g. putting the label into a `Grid` and use a fixed column width.

The reason for that behavior could be that `StackLayout` has a [default width of `Auto`](http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/09/xamarin-xaml-vs-microsoft-xaml-the-devil-is-in-the-details/) (if nothing explicitly set) and the label doesn't know how big it could be. If you set a width, the label can grow up to that size.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432087/426227) brought me on the idea.